# How to *ngFor loop through two columns in Angular 7/ Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an array called favoriteList. This contains data that I am retrieving from Firestore, containing pictures, titles and descriptions etc. I am trying to loop through this data, displaying the images in a two column row layout.
However, when I try to loop through the data, it loops over twice, instead of the desired one time.
I have tried to following code below, which results in the image I have attached.

[image]

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid *ngFor ="let favorite of favoriteList">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of favorite?.favoriteList;let i = index;">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="4">
          <ion-card>   
            <img [src]="item.image[0]">
            <div class="card-title">{{ item?.title}}</div>
            <div>{{item?.description}}</div>  
          </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="4">
          <ion-card>   
            <img [src]="item.image[0]">
            <div class="card-title">{{ item?.title}}</div>
            <div>{{item?.description}}</div>  
          </ion-card>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-grid>  
</ion-content>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using the value of 4 on your col.? Do you really want an empty 4 column on the right?

Comment: can you share what data is in favoriteList?

Comment: @catcat You display the same data twice in `ion-col`

Answer (score 0):

You were outputting two columns, so it appears to be looping twice, but really your two columns were identical, I removed one below.

```
<ion-content>
          <ion-grid *ngFor ="let favorite of favoriteList">
              <ng-container>
            <ion-row>
            <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let item of favorite?.favoriteList;let i = index;">
                <ion-card>   
                        <img [src]="item.image[0]">
                        <div class="card-title">{{ item?.title}}</div>
                        <div>{{item?.description}}</div>  
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ng-container>
          </ion-grid>  
        </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is fine, you just displayed the same `ion-card` twice

```
<ion-card>   
  <img [src]="item.image[0]">
  <div class="card-title">{{ item?.title }}</div>
  <div>{{ item?.description }}</div>  
</ion-card>
```

You achieve a two column display by splitting the 12 column display to 6 columns. No need to use a `ng-container`, just loop on what you want to display. In your case the `ion-cols`.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid *ngFor ="let favorite of favoriteList">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let item of favorite?.favoriteList">
        <ion-card>   
          <img src="item.image[0]">
          <div class="card-title">{{ item?.title }}</div>
          <div>{{ item?.description }}</div>  
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>  
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

only you need to do somenthing like:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let item of data">
      <ion-card>Your Item</ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```